# Monorepo Vue + Nestjs domain and platform object sharing

Tags: nestjs, monorepo

Objective:

- Use a monorepo structure, in which I can share domain models and generic implementations (using a provider pattern) across the different Bounded Contexts
- Ability to deploy each bounded context or client application independently of the others (thus all of this in a monolith under one `src` directory is not acceptable.

Background: Typical tech stacks for me is Angular + .Net Core. I am starting to move away from Angular and also exploring the code sharing benefits if I do my API development with Nestjs.

I am trying to figure out the best way to set up shared code between the client and API and running into some issues.

I have the following directory structure. I would like to figure out the best way to shared the models that are in the `domain/models/comestibles` in the `api/comestibles` and in the `web` application. I am ok with putting all of the shared code in a `packages` folder as well (was looking at Lerna)

[image]

I can easily point the code to the directory from the `api/comestibles`, but that is making the `dist` folder structure undesirable and also messing up things (like Swagger). I also had the change the `outDir` in the `tsconfig.json` from

`"outDir": "./dist"`

to

`"outDir": "./dist/api/comestibles/src"`

This broke other things in the application though as the directory structure is really altered.

I looked at setting up Bit and I have tracked some files, but I do not see any packages created for those files. Perhaps I am using it incorrectly though. I was also looking at Lerna for this. Given this is the first time I have done a full-stack application via scripting, I am unfamiliar with the best architecture for this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Nx.dev plug-in solved my problem.

https://github.com/ZachJW34/nx-plus/tree/master/libs/vue